# Exectution of software slower in IDE, than outside?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, execution

If I run a developed software in the IDE I have two opportunities:

1. Debug Mode
2. Normale Mode

**Debug Mode:** Software is slower, than in normale mode, because the system needs time to watch all the variables and the program execution.

**Normale Mode:** Software should run as desired.

Is there a difference in the execution time and the execution itself, if I run the software in the IDE or I start it from the command line?

I use Java software, developed in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Normal mode there should not be any different between running the application from Eclipse and from the command line.

This is assuming that the same values for the various memory options (heap size, perm gen space) are used.

Comment: And the same runtime.